# How to edit a element from a list that is stored in Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have a OberservableCollection stored in my Isolated Storage.

New a Scene contains a List. And a Light contains an Xpos en Ypos property.

How can I edit this list?

So I would like to retrieve it from the IsoStorage, change the 2 properties and then save it again.

Hope someone can help me out :).

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection`'s have a colleciton changed event which passes who sent it (the base collection) as well as a series of arguments. You can listen to this `CollectionChanged` event, listen to only newly added items and perform your operation on the item.

If your collection is a list of referenced objects, you can perform your edits on the objects directly and the changes will be mirrored in the list. However, if you are using value typed list, then you need a way of flagging the item such that when you remove it from the list, and re-add it, the add doesn't trigger an infinite loop.

**Example:**

```
class Clean<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public bool IsClean;
    public Clean(T value, bool clean)
    {
        Value = value;
        IsClean = clean;
    }
}
```

This Clean class is used to store a value as well as a flag marking if its been processed or not.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Clean<int>> myCollection = new    ObservableCollection<Clean<int>>();
        myCollection.CollectionChanged += x_CollectionChanged;

        myCollection.Add(new Clean<int>(2,false));

    }

    static void x_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Grab the collection being modified
        ObservableCollection<Clean<int>> collection = sender as ObservableCollection<Clean<int>>;
        if (collection == null)
        {
            // do some error checking action
        }
        //Only look at items being added
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //New item has been added
            foreach (Clean<int> newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                ///Only perform the operation on new "dirty" objects
                if (!newItem.IsClean)
                {
                    collection.Remove(newItem);
                    //Add the new modified value and mark it as clean so that 
                    //    this process isn't run again
                    collection.Add(new Clean<int>(newItem.Value * 2,true));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Sources:**

`ObservableCollection` [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would just retrieve the collection as per normal...

```
public IEnumerable<Scene> GetScenes()
{
    using (var filesystem = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Scenes", FileMode.Open, filesystem))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<Scene>));
            return serializer.ReadObject(fs) as IEnumerable<Scene>;
        }
    }
}
```

... then edit what you need to...

```
var myScenes = new ObservableCollection<Scene>(GetScenes());
var itemToUpdate = myScenes.Where(i => i.PropertyToCheck == "value to check");
itemToUpdate.PropertyToSet = "new value";
```

...and save the collection back to isolated storage using the same key to identify it.

```
SaveScenes(myScenes);
```

It will overwrite the previous collection if you use `FileMode.Create`.

```
public void SaveScenes(IEnumerable<Scene> scenes)
{
    using (var filesystem = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Scenes", FileMode.Create, filesystem))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(IEnumerable<Scene>));
            serializer.WriteObject(fs, Scenes);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find a [similar example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821020.aspx).